# Is there any way to get the id of the processor currently running a .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I'm doing some testing of an application on a multi-processor machine.  I am curious if it is possible to see what processor a section of code was running on.  I was hoping to see the distribution across the processors when the code is under load.

Comment: You could p/invoke Win32s `GetCurrentProcessorNumber()`